# Vector of shared pointers , memory problems after clearing the vector

Tags: c++, memory, vector, smart-pointers

I realized that after calling `vector.clear()` which hold shared pointers, the destructors of the object which own by `shared_ptr` is not being released.

Code example can be seen below . Even `vector.clear()` being called, destructor called after shared pointer goes beyond the scope.My question is - do I have to delete all smart pointers inside the vector manually by resetting them? Is there any easier way that you can advice ?

```
Output :   

constructor
I am here
destructor

Code:

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A(){cout << "constructor" << endl;};
    ~A(){cout << "destructor"  << endl;};
};

int main( )
{
    shared_ptr<A> sharedptr (new A);
    std::vector<shared_ptr<A> > test;
    test.push_back(sharedptr);

    test.clear();
    cout << "I am here" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

you have two copies of `shared_ptr<A>` in this case, one is the `sharedptr` variable and the other as an element in the vector.

do this instead

```
test.push_back(std::move(sharedptr));
```

note now the original `sharedptr` has it's internal moved and no longer usable. The other thing is don't do anything at all, this is a perfectly valid usage of of shared_ptr and `sharedptr` will clean up itself after it goes out of scope.

Comment: I would add that in the case shown in the question, I would actually prefer constructing the vector in place in the vector via `emplace_back`, in order to avoid having an accessible named variable (`sharedptr`) whose use would be dangerous after `std::move`.

Comment: As @us2012 wrote, this seems like a way to get yourself in trouble. OP's code works exactly as it's supposed to; `shared_ptr` is copied, which increases the reference count, and then correctly calls the destructor when both copies get out of scope.

Answer (score 12):

The problem arises when the `push_back` adds a *copy* of the `shared_ptr` to the vector, leaving the original dangling until main exists. If you don't make the shared_ptr in main scope, the problem does not happen. Just avoid making the shared_ptr in main scope. Make it as a temporary right in the `push_back` call.

```
Output is now:   

constructor
I am almost there
destructor
I am here

New code:

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
  A(){cout << "constructor" << endl;};
  ~A(){cout << "destructor"  << endl;};
};

int main( )
{
  vector<shared_ptr<A> > test;
  test.push_back(shared_ptr<A>(new A));
  cout << "I am almost there" << endl;
  test.clear();
  cout << "I am here" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: what about maked_shared or emplace_back?

Answer (score 4):

Here **sharedptr** and the element in **vector** share the same object which will result in invoking constructor and destructor only once.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the destructor isn't called until later is that your variable `sharedptr` is still in scope until the end of your `main()`. There are a few ways around this if you really want it cleaned up before then. The most obvious way to fix this is to only use `sharedptr` in a quick block scope:

```cpp
int main( )
{
    std::vector<shared_ptr<A> > test;
    {
      shared_ptr<A> sharedptr (new A);
      test.push_back(sharedptr);
    }
    test.clear();
    cout << "I am here" << endl;
}
```

Or alternatively, never create the `sharedptr` variable at all:

```cpp
int main( )
{
    std::vector<shared_ptr<A> > test;
    test.push_back( shared_ptr<A>(new A) );
    test.clear();
    cout << "I am here" << endl;
}
```